# How to take a screenshot of the form1 while changing a trackBar value in ValueChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms

The ValueChanged event

```
private void trackBarHue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBarHue.Value < filteredImages.Count)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = filteredImages[trackBarHue.Value];

        // Take a screenshot of the form and save it
        TakeScreenshotAndSave(this);
    }
}
```

the TakeScreenshotAndSave method code

```
int screenshotsCounter = 0;
private void TakeScreenshotAndSave(Form form)
{
    // Create a bitmap of the same size as the form
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height))
    {
        // Create a graphics object from the bitmap
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            // Take the screenshot from the upper-left corner of the form
            g.CopyFromScreen(form.Location, Point.Empty, form.Size);
        }

        // Define the path and file name for the screenshot
        string fileName = $"FormScreenshot_{screenshotsCounter++}.png";
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"d:\screenshots", fileName);

        // Save the screenshot to the specified path
        bmp.Save(fullPath);

        // Optionally, display a message or log the save operation
        Console.WriteLine($"Screenshot saved to: {fullPath}");
    }
}
```

the problem is when i first time run the application and it;s showing the trackBar and the image in the pictureBox this is how it looks like:

[image: first time running]

now I change the trackBar value by one tick to the right:

[image: trackBar is on value 1]

the first two images taken by me when the application is running.

now this images are the saved screenshots by the method TakeScreenshotAndSave:

you can see now that the first taken screenshot the image in the pictureBox is not matching the trackBar value.  the trackBar value is 1 but the screenshot show the original image like when running the application first time.  but it should show the image in index 1 value 1 ( the two images i show above ).

[image: the trackBar value not matching the image in the pictureBox]

so either some problem with the index in the ValueChanged event or maybe something with the index in the method TakeScreenshotAndSave. not sure.

when i change the trackBar value it's showing the correct image in the pictureBox but when it's taking at the same time the screenshots in the screenshots it's not showing the correct image that should match the trackBar value.

Comment: Add trackBarHue.Update() so the bar is repainted with the new value before you take the screenshot.

Comment: ...and maybe refresh the PictureBox, too :)